# Timer based if statements with variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, avaudiorecorder

I have a timer setup that is triggering and reading the iPhone mic input level. I have some if statements that say if the incoming volume is "this" then change the views background color to "this".

Everything works okay but naturally the meter goes in succession of 0,1,2,3,4,5 then back down in the reverse order of 5,4,3,2,1,0. However I do not want this to occur. I want to jump all the way back to "0" when the volume tries to go back down.

So what I did, was create two variables. One called "previousValue" and the other "currentValue" to keep track of where they are in the succession of levels I am at - then one last if statement that says if previousValue > currentValue (going down) then jump back to "0". However, it's just not working. Maybe I am doing something wrong here?

A little help would be very appreciated! Thank you! Here is the code so you can get a better look at what I am trying to achieve.

I declare the INT values below the implementation
    int previousValue;
    int currentValue;

then set a starting point in the viewDidLoad
    previousValue = 0;
    currentValue = 0;

```
if (meterResults > 0.0) {
    NSLog(@"0");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = 0;
}

if (meterResults > 0.1){
    NSLog(@"1");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = 1;
}

if (meterResults > 0.2){
    NSLog(@"2");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = 2;
}

if (meterResults > 0.3){
    NSLog(@"3");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = 3;
}

if (meterResults > 0.4){
    NSLog(@"4");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = 4;
}

if (previousValue > currentValue) {

    NSLog(@"Hello, don't go in reverse order go straight to Red");

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode, retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aroth's answer is right, but you'll still have a problem after you take the advice.  Since you're sampling an analog signal, successive measurements will be roughly continuous.  If you change the current value to zero, the next value read will appear to your code to be increasing again, which it isn't.

Don't lie about the current value to make the UI behave as you wish.  Instead, model the thing you care about explicitly, which is the instantaneous first derivative.  That would go like this:

```
currentValue = (int)floor(meterResults * 10.0);
NSInteger currentFirstDerivative = currentValue - previousValue;
// since the timer repeats at a fixed interval, this difference is like a 1st derivative

if (currentFirstDerivative < 0) {
    // it's going down, make the view red
} else {
    switch (currentValue) {
    case 1:
        // change colors here
        break;
    case 2:
    // and so on
}

// now, for next time
previousValue = currentValue;
```

Comment: Yea, I think you're right @danh - anyway I could do a quick code chat with you or something - I think it's close just a few little errors I wanna ask ya about on this concept? And possibly a quick chat would be better? Really thank you so much - this looks promising.

Comment: I am on it here - if you have a quick minute? - http://www.stypi.com/seanherman/If%20Statement%20Help

Comment: Thank you for your time @danh - I owe ya a coffee mate!

Comment: Hey @danh - Just curious, let's say I wanted to do a range of meter levels to play one sound. But the sound is triggering every time the timer hits. Any ways you can think of making that happen? So - if meterResults and between these ranges play this looped sound otherwise  stop the sound. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside of your `if` statements, you are doing:

```
previousValue = currentValue;
```

So of course the comparison you have at the end there will never evaluate to `true` since they will always be equal at that point.

I'd suggest doing something like:

```
if (previousValue > currentValue) {
    currentValue = 0;
}
```

...at the *beginning* of your code.

Comment: Thanks - how would just adding the above code at the beginning make it work? I already set both prev/current to 0 in the the viewDidLoad.

Comment: It works because it moves the comparison so that it happens before you do `previousValue = currentValue`, which destroys the actual `previousValue`.  By "beginning of your code" I meant "before the start of the `if` blocks", not "inside of `viewDidLoad`".